# Ant taskdef - requires both classpath and -lib parameter?

Tags: java, ant, classloader

Whilst working on an Ant script today I noticed that even though my classpath was defined with the classpath attribute, I still needed to use `-lib` when starting ant (ie `ant -lib myjar.jar`) to make it run properly.

```
<project name="My Project" default="run-task" basedir=".">
  <target name="run-task" description="Use the Ant Task">
    <taskdef name="TaskName" classname="mypackage.MyClass" classpath="myjar.jar"/>
    <TaskName />
  </target>
</project>
```

Is there a quirk in the classloading for ant that requires this?

Comment: I should work without `-lib`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work the same.

```
<path id="ant.tasks">
   <fileset dir="lib" includes="myspecialant.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="TaskName" classname="mypackage.MyClass" classpathref="ant.tasks"/>
```

I prefer to manage my classpaths at the top of my build separate to the logic that uses them. Make troubleshooting simpler.

Comment: Thanks Mark - that wasn't my question - I was talking about specifying `-lib jarname.jar` at the command line.

Comment: @hawkeye Understood, which was why I suggested an alternative approach. As Nicolas stated it *should* work without "-lib". I'm personally allergic to builds that require special handling for 3rd party tasks. They should be setup properly within the build file. Try out my approach and see if it solves the problem.